# Capture Desktiop Notification in Linux

Tags: linux, notifications, fedora, libnotify, notify-send

Hi Guys I'm using Fedora 32 Workstation.

I wanted to know is there a way to capture desktop Notification using some shell script or python script.

I want to keep a log of all the desktop notification.

So far I am able to only create notification using the `notify-send` command but not how to capture the notification.

Comment: Is this what you are looking for https://askubuntu.com/questions/89279/listening-to-incoming-libnotify-notifications-using-dbus ?